# UITextView dynamic tintColor

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextview

I'm trying to dynamically hide and display the caret of a `UITextView` by setting its `tintColor` to clear and black respectively.  When I set the tint of the text view initially in on `init`, the correct color is displayed.  If I subsequently try to set the tint while the field is selected, however, the color doesn't update.  Only when `resignFirstResponder` is called does the color update.  What is the appropriate method for changing the tint color while a text view is selected?

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that resignFirstResponder helps. I resign, and them immediately reassign the textView as the first responder, the colour is updated and the selection actually remains intact. Perfect.

Comment: Any solution to this? This is very annoying. And resigning the first responder and then immediately becoming first responder again doesn't seem like a workable solution because it causes animation issues for me. The keyboard doesn't animate, but my text box does because it thinks it needs to go down and back up. Even if I did a workaround to deal with the animation, resign/become first responder seems like a bad solution.

Comment: I added code to unregister from keyboard events and then re-register after becoming responder again (this avoids the issue of me quickly animating my text box down and up). However, I still have the issue of the keyboard flashing to all caps mode and then back to lower case...I think this is happening because when it first becomes responder it doesn't know yet whether to be all caps or lower case. So there's a quick moment where it's trying to figure it out. And the reason I don't see it every time I actually open and close the keyboard normally is because of the animation. This is a guess.

Comment: So the resignFirstResponder / becomeFirstResponder solution is not very nice :( I'm hoping for a better one...